# How can I use PowerShell to install this service fabric project?

Tags: c#, .net, powershell, azure, azure-service-fabric

I have the following folder structure once I package my [Service Fabric](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/service-fabric/) `NS1.NS2.MicroServicesTest` project (written in `C#`, using `.NET`):

```
pkg
 |-NS1.NS2.MicroServicesTest.MicroServiceA
 |-NS1.NS2.MicroServicesTest.MicroServiceB
 |-NS1.NS2.MicroServicesTest.MicroServiceC
 |-NS1.NS2.MicroServicesTest.MicroServiceD
 |-ApplicationManifest.xml
```

I am trying to deploy this package using the following `PowerShell` script:

```
Copy-ServiceFabricApplicationPackage pkg -ImageStoreConnectionString file:C:\SfDevCluster\Data\ImageStoreShare -ApplicationPackagePathInImageStore NS1.NS2.MicroServicesTest
Register-ServiceFabricApplicationType NS1.NS2.MicroServicesTest
New-ServiceFabricApplication fabric:/NS1.NS2.MicroServicesTest NS1.NS2.MicroServicesTest 1.0.0
```

It fails on the last command, `New-ServiceFabricApplication`, with the following error:

> New-ServiceFabricApplication : Application type and version not found

Where have I gone wrong? I have tried to follow this [tutorial](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/service-fabric-automate-powershell/), albeit it kind of uses a base case in its example, whereas my project has 4 microservices as part of it, and an odd naming convention, which makes it even more confusing...

**Edit**: When I run the `Get-ServiceFabricApplicationType` command, I see:

```
ApplicationTypeName    : MicroServicesTestType
ApplicationTypeVersion : 1.0.0
DefaultParameters      : { "MicroServiceA_InstanceCount" = "-1";
                         "MicroServiceB_InstanceCount" = "-1";
                         "MicroServiceC_Endpoint" = "defaultValue";
                         "MicroServiceC_InstanceCount" = "-1";
                         "MicroServiceC_MaxRecords" = "100";
                         "MicroServiceD_InstanceCount" = "-1" }
```

Comment: After registering it, does your Application Type show up when calling 'Get-ServiceFabricApplicationType'? Is your Application Type version 1.0.0?

Comment: @LoekD Yes, it does. I've edited the question to reflect this.

Comment: Can you try this: New-ServiceFabricApplication -ApplicationName fabric:/MicroServicesTest/MicroServicesTest  -ApplicationTypeName "MicroServicesTest" -ApplicationTypeVersion "1.0.0"

Comment: @LoekD Still the same error, I'm afraid. I've updated my question yet again because I didn't correctly set it up originally (sorry about that)...I have an odd naming convention for this project/microservices.

Comment: (This won't fix it, but I postfix my Application Type name with "....Type" to make it simpler to see the difference in the explorer and logs.) 

Can you try using names without periods in them?

Comment: @LoekD You were correct in your answer, I just posted the wrong data for you, it seems `Get-ServiceFabricApplicationType` returns `MicroServicesTestType` for the `ApplicationTypeName`, and I needed to use that to run the command: `New-ServiceFabricApplication fabric:/ MicroServicesTestType MicroServicesTestType 1.0.0`

Comment: @LoekD If you post that as the answer, I'll give it to you! Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(from discussion to answer)

- After registering it, validate that your Application Type shows up when calling 'Get-ServiceFabricApplicationType'
- Check your Application Type version 1.0.0?
- Try using this command: `New-ServiceFabricApplication fabric:/ MicroServicesTestType MicroServicesTestType 1.0.0`